# Is it worth applying a MAC on data in a HSM?

Tags: aes, cbc, hmac, cryptographic-hardware

I'm building a basic HSM out of an Arduino, and am using the following scheme to store data:

- Master symmetric key $k_m$ stored in firmware (secure bit set to prevent trivial extraction).
- Secondary symmetric keys $k_s$ stored as plaintext in web application database, one per user.
- HSM record key $k_r$ generated by <del>xor'ing the two keys together</del> computing $AES(k_s, k_m)$, using AES-128-ECB. This means that both the HSM and application server would have to be compromised in order to reveal the key.
- AES-128-CBC used to encrypt the data, using a unique pseudo-random IV and the record key.
- Each record on the HSM consists of a plaintext record ID, the IV, and a data block.

Is it worth applying a HMAC-SHA1 hash over this data to provide integrity and authenticity checking? If so, what should I use as key material?

Comment: For experimentation and learning, right? :)

Comment: Mainly. Ultimately I'll be using it in a site that isn't security critical - just a game. The HSM will be handling password reset questions and "select 3 letters from your secret word" type authentication, as additional defense against remote attackers.

Comment: Will there really be only one "HSM record key"? $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer Per record, yes. Does that sound odd to you?

Comment: I just found your use of the singular odd. $\:$ How will you do the cipher operations while still having $\hspace{.5 in}$ "that both the HSM and application server would have to be compromised in order to reveal the key[s]"?

Comment: @RickyDemer The server sends the secondary key to the HSM device when a request is needed, where it computes the record key. Since the key will be in RAM, and that's inside the uC chip, it cannot be retrieved feasibly in an on-site environment. Tampering with the HSM code would also be immediately detected, because re-flashing it would mean an outage.

Comment: Is there a reason for just doing xor-encryption with the master symmetric key, rather than something that would make a related-key attack more difficult after a compromise of the application server? $\;\;$

Comment: Simplicity. I couldn't think of a scenario where the xor would be problematic. Could you provide details on a practical related-key attack for this setup?

Comment: No, since I'm not aware of any. $\:$ However, my understanding is that related key $\hspace{1.4 in}$ attacks are usually based on xor relations. $\;\;\;$

Comment: I could easily switch to AES-128-ECB for deriving the key. Essentially I'd do $k_r = AES(k_s, k_m)$ where $k_s$ is the secondary key and $k_m$ is the master key in the firmware.

Comment: Is "each record on the HSM" stored **in** the HSM, or in the host (initialy enciphered by the HSM, deciphered on demand)? The later is often used to increase the apparent capacity of the HSM; it makes a MAC of the data more useful. Also: what about power loss during update of the HSM (or the host, if that's  where "record on the HSM" are)? Also: do you assume the memory used for records is error-free, perhaps except for power loss during write?

Comment: @fgrieu Each "record on the HSM" is stored inside the HSM. I hadn't considered the power loss issue, but a solution would be to store each entry twice and alternate writes across the two by switching an entry's flag as an atomic operation. As per memory correctness, I generally don't see it being a problem, though I can see why a HMAC would work well for such a situation. Perhaps you should write an answer to reflect what you've said here - it seems like a cogent argument to use a MAC.

Comment: You wrote the expression for $k_r$ differently in your comment and your post; $k_m$ should be the block $\hspace{.4 in}$ cipher key. $\:$ It would take slightly more space and time, but you might use SIV mode instead, $\hspace{.5 in}$ where one of the headers is the record ID. $\:$ (www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/siv.pdf) $\;\;$

Comment: Whoops, typo! Fixed. Am using a pre-written AES lib so I'd rather avoid code for custom modes.

Comment: Which input do you put where when you write  AES(.,.) ? $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer I usually write it as `AES(block, key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing an HSM or other secure device is relatively easy; making it reliable even in the absence of adversary requires careful engineering; making it safe against adversaries with some level of physical access is hard; demonstrating that it is safe (for some definition of that) is even harder.

One thing to worry about is integrity of stored data (including keys) w.r.t. to both accidental events and deliberate attacks. One should consider problems often neglected in other embedded developments:

- memory writes during power loss, which can leave a data block partially erased or written, in manners depending heavily on technology:

  - for RAM, it is easy to observe a data block left partially written, with e.g. low addresses holding new data, high address still holding old data;
  - sometime it can be observed that in between, a word is garbled apparently randomly;
  - for EEPROM and Flash, the physical erasure before write (typically, with alignment to some page boundary) is often apparent;
  - with EEPROM or Flash, it might be observable that some memory cells are left in an unstable state where the content read (until another erase or write) will vary randomly, or/and as a function of operating temperature (if you do not trust me on this one, ask the IC vendor to put in writing what it guarantees about what's read in memory that was being written or erased at time of power loss, with rationale at the physical level to support that);
- non-deterministic CPU operation, which itself can occurs when operating conditions (e.g. power supply) are non-nominal, and there is no adequate (e.g. voltage) sensors to block operation in these conditions;
- cosmic rays; incidence vary enormously with memory technology, capacity, altitude, solar activity, [location on surface of earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_Anomaly), and (metaphorically) phase of the moon; search [Single Event Upset RAM](https://www.google.com/search?q=Single%20Event%20upset%20RAM) for references;
- deliberate [fault attacks](http://www.naccache.fr/courses/RES/document/CAI94B6L.pdf) trying to cause or simulate some of the above.

Carefully designed and tested measures (software and/or hardware) to deal with at least power loss is a must. Some kind of integrity protection on top of that is a good idea. One option is to substitute AES-128-CBC with [AES-GCM](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf); another is to use a separate MAC, e.g. HMAC-SHA1 (if we neglect [side-channel leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack) issues, it is fine to do this on the plaintext, and probably fine to use $k_r$ as the HMAC-SHA1 key, though $\operatorname{AES}(\operatorname{key}=k'_m,\operatorname{data}=k_s)$ would be more academic and work with any MAC). If that's tolerable from a functional standpoint, moving the HSM to a [zeroized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroisation) state in case of error is the safest from a security standpoint (but zeroization itself requires care; something like "on error detected erase $k_s$", where that erasure is performed in two halves, potentially leaves open to an attack halving the effective key size).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read a bit more about cryptographic design before getting into design of a HSM.  Designing a HSM is basically designing a cryptographic protocol.

For instance, using AES-128-CBC is a bad idea, as it does not provide message authentication; instead, you should use authenticated encryption.

Similarly, rather than deriving a derived key in some funny way from two pieces, I would recommend that you compute it as the hash of the two pieces (unless you really want one piece to be reconstructable from the derived key plus another piece -- that doesn't seem desirable to me).  If I understand correctly, someone who learns a record key $k_r$ and learns the secondary key $k_s$ can derive the master key.  That doesn't sound like a desirable property from what I can see.

There are a bunch of good papers on analysis of HSMs from the University of Cambridge (Ross Anderson and collaborators).  Those papers show many security flaws in deployed HSMs, because they were ignorant of design principles for strong cryptographic protocols.  I recommmend you take a look at those papers and learn from others' mistakes.

Comment: That's only if the OP's ordering of the inputs to AES(.,.) is the same as I think me and you would use.

Comment: @Ricky Demer: thanks for pointing an earlier inversion of $k_s$ and $k_m$ in my text.

Comment: +1 for pointing the difficulty at defining the right protocol to be implemented by the HSM. Also: indeed, $k_r=\operatorname{Hash}(k_s||k_m)$, or $k_r=\operatorname{HMAC}(\operatorname{key}=k_m,\operatorname{message}=k_s)$ can help.

Comment: I'd have gone for EAX mode or GCM immediately if possible, but I'm using a pre-written AES library that doesn't offer such modes, and I've already eaten up half of my program space with libraries without even implementing the storage or request processing code. Adding EAX or GCM would be tricky to get right, and there might not be space. I'll take your advice on the hash, though.

Comment: fgrieu's first suggestion seems worse than his second suggestion (and worse than "encrypt $k_s$ with $k_m$").

Comment: @Rick Demer: $k_r=\operatorname{Hash}(k_s||k_m)$ is in D.W.'s answer. $k_r=\operatorname{HMAC}(\operatorname{key}=k_m,\operatorname{message}=k_s)$ is my attempt to slightly strengthen that under the assumption that pairs $(k_s,k_r)$ leak (as hypothesized by D.W.). I do not see how that is worse than $k_r=\operatorname{AES}(\operatorname{key}=k_m,\operatorname{data}=k_s)$, except if $\operatorname{HMAC}$ was more vulnerable than $\operatorname{AES}$ to side channel attacks. In the attack model, $k_r$ and $k_m$ are both equally secret, thus everything envisonned for $k_r$ (except XOR) is fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought he had removed that suggestion and you were putting it forward again. $\:$ I wasn't $\:$ saying that the HMAC method would be worse than the AES method, although I do think that's the case, since AES was specifically designed for properties that imply it's a PRF family, unlike HMAC.